# How can I write to a new column in a CSV file using VB Script?

Tags: csv, vbscript

how can I make the 'Hi' write to a new column (but same row) in CSV? I thought the comma should do the trick but it doesn't.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objLogFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("test.csv", _ 
    ForWriting, True)

objLogFile.Write "Hello,"
objLogFile.Write "Hi"
objLogFile.Writeline
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma has nothing to do with it. The `Write` leaves the current position on the same line, and the `WriteLine` moves it to the next line. So your script produces this:

```
Hello,Hi
```

which, I presume, is what you want.

Comment: Thanks but how can I put values onto the next column?

Comment: I think @Ekkehard.Horner may have worked out what you mean! What application are you using to read the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case your real problem is that the application you use to view test.csv shows `Hello,Hi` in **one** cell: You need to tell that application to use comma as field separator.